# Why my app crashes when copying an array with certain strings to a dictionary?

Tags: iphone, ios4, sdk, nsdictionary

I'm working with a tableview that shows an array of dictionaries. Everything was working fine until I wanted to add an array of strings to the new dictionaries.

The strings in the array have the format "CALL 34". When I add the array the app shows the tableview again but after a second it crashes without showing anything at the console.

The very rare thing is that the app works fine if the strings are between "CALL 1" and "CALL 32", or between "CALL 99" and "CALL 100". The console shows the "modifying layer that is being finalized" error when it works tho.

I NSLog'd the array before adding it and the strings are all fine.
Any idea would help as I'm completly lost!
Thanks

---

I tryed not releasing anything in that class and the problem is solved (I should find what was making it crash...). The class is a heritated class.

Comment: Is this a debug release? What was the error in the console? Have you checked the device for a crash log?

Comment: the console sometimes shows the "modifying layer that is being finalized" error (when it doesnt crash). Dont know how to check deeper :S

Comment: Show code. If your code is too long, try creating a minimal test case that reproduces your problem — sometimes doing so gives you insight as to what’s the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without showing code, it is impossible to say exactly.  As well, if there is a crash, there is a backtrace.  Show it, too.

Sounds like a memory management issue.

Comment: the code is so long and disperse I dont know where to start copying as Im not sure where the problem comes from. The console shows the "modifying layer that is being finalized" error when it doesnt crash.